# How to send back a value from Promise.coroutine?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, generator, bluebird

How do I resolve a promise when using `promise.coroutine`?

The following function returns a `promise`.

```
function send() {
    // .. some code

    return Promise.coroutine(function* () {
        try {
            let invitationList = yield q.join(instructor);
            for (let invite of invitationList) {
                // Send multiple emails
                // Email.sendTemplate returns a promise
                yield Email.sendTemplate(invite.email_template_id, { email: invite.email });
                // how to send the response back
            }
        } catch (err) { }
    })();
}
```

If the handler of the function is written as:

```
send()
  .then(r => console.log(r) )
  .catch(err => console.log(err) )
```

How do I return the value in `then`? Currently `undefined` is received with the `then` function.

Comment: One possible way is to push the responses in array and then after for loop return the result(to make code shorter you could use .map).

Comment: @JaromandaX Typo!

Comment: are you saying that `r` is not logged? or not the value you were expecting?

Comment: @JaromandaX It is undefined.

Comment: is the promise that `Email.sendTemplate` returns supposed to resolve to something other than undefined? it's not clear from your code what the "promised" value is

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, it returns an object on success.